# Why can't I commit changes in a conflicted state?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

As we all know, merging branches in subversion (or any other revision control system for that matter) every so often results in conflicts. Somtimes these conflicts can be very complicated to resolve. Yet you are required to do so before committing the changes to the repository.

As the merge itself obviously will apply a set of changes, any modifications to resolve the conflicts will be applied on top of these. In the end it is impossible to separate the changes from the automatic merge from the manual modifications applied to resolve the conflicts.

It is not uncommon that issues are introduced when merging, not only due the challenge of integration itself, but from incorrect decisions when resolving merge conflicts. It would be easier to track these issues down fast if the decisions made when resolving any conflicts were clearly visible in a separate commit. It would also be easier to have a colleague review what you have done to resolve the conflicts.

This would be possible if committing changes in a conflicted state would be allowed. The automatic merge including conflicts could be committed first and conflict resolution afterwards.

Obviously you could argue that it is undesired to have a repository in a conflicted state, but you could always have the client access a last-unconflicted-revision. I would rather have a repository in a conflicted state every once in a while, instead of a repository broken by incorrect merge resolution.

Are there any reasons why can't I commit changes in a conflicted state?

Optional: Am I missing some subversion magic, are there tools to find out what decisions were made to resolve conflicts?

Optional: Does git or any other revision handling system handle this better than subversion?

Answer (score 2):

Think about what it would *mean* for your repository to be in a conflicted state. What that means is that there is more than one possible correct latest version of the code, which means that you have forked the repository. Source control systems already have means by which a repository can be forked.

If you really don't know what the solution to the merge conflict is, you are forking your code, so you should do a proper fork and not try to implement some sort of pseudo or quasi-fork into your source control system!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Why would it mean there is more than one possible correct latest version? The HEAD revision is obviously the latest revision and by committing the merge, with conflicts or not, you indicate that the intention is to bring these changes into the branch. If there are unresolved conflicts that just means there are integration work left to do. Just as well as there could be integration work left to do that is unrelated to the version handling system.